# My ethernet and Wi-Fi are connected but, i can't seem to connect to the internet

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, macos, internet

In the morning of christmas, i was browsing the internet on a Mac OSX El Capitan version 10.11 laptop. My internet connection stopped working on my laptop. That is, **Ethernet and Wi-Fi simultaneously.** Initially, i thought i had ISP problems. So i restarted both the laptop and the router. Still nothing in Wi-Fi and Ethernet. Yet, i discovered other people had logged in were using Wi-Fi from the same router. Also, the internet works alright in recovery mode.

Before i continue i'm using a  **MacBook Pro mid-2012 version and now i'm using macOS Sierra Version 10.12.** I updated hoping that that will fix the problem. It didn't. In addition, i tried using a mobile network tethering to share a connection and that didn't work as well.

Here are some methods i've used to try and fix the problem. I followed exactly  what was done here after reading this sentence on this post [Now I've tried the following, in different order and a number of times, to no avail:](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177873/full-wi-fi-ethernet-signal-but-no-internet)

After running, `ifconconfig en1` on the terminal. This is what i got today.

```
en1: flags=8823<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    ether 2c:be:08:e6:87:3c
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
    status: inactive
```

At the moment, i want to try these methods to fix the problem.

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpAfpPiRSaE&t=2s
2. Factory reset and reinstall OS. Since the network settings will be lost

I'm thinking of doing the second one.

I hope what i've pointed out will suffice to help me solve the problem. I would really appreciate your help to solve this problem.

Regards,
Ben.

Answer (score 1):

The problem came back in the same computer. The connection was restored after rerunning the Windscribe app. In addition, this app was available in both instances where my internet connection disappears. It seems that it's activity without closing it correctly caused